# SAS Counting Keywords Across rows

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I am trying to generate the count of times any of the strings in a list appears in each row.

I am using a big data, with many columns, but the columns of interest start with D_I10_ .
This dataset has ICD codes for every visit a patient makes to the hospital. But I am interested to find out the number of times a patient ended up with an alcohol related ICD code in the hospital. The ICD codes of each visit is listed in columns starting with D_I10_ .
Here is what I have done so far:

```
data home.new2;
set home.new;
array d1 D_I10_;  /*this is trying to tell which columns to pick*/
array c{3} $ 4 _temporary_ ('X45' 'Y15' 'X65'); /* these are the strings I am interested in, there are way more than three, so I need an automatic way to do it*/
visits=0;  /* this is just stating the variable i want to make, which is # of visits based on those string appearance*/ 
do i= 1 to dim(d1); /* this is a attempt to do the counting*/
if whichc(d1[i],of c(*))>0 then do visit=visit+count(whichc(d1[i],of c(*))>0);leave;end;
end;
run;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :slightly_smiling_face:

Comment: I don't see how knowing that a single medical record had one versus two or more of those codes makes any difference in determining if the visit was related to alcohol.  Instead you want to count observations (or perhaps visits if there are multiple observations per visit).

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all the `D_I10_` columns and do a `COUNT` if the targets can be embedded in a larger word, or loop `FINDW` if the targets are words themselves.

Example:

```
  length all_D $32767; drop all_D;
  all_D = catx(' ', of D_I10_:);
  count_X45 = count(all_D, 'X45');
  count_Y15 = count(all_D, 'Y15');
  count_X65 = count(all_D, 'X65');
  count_all = sum(of count_:);
```

or

```
data want;
  set have;
  length haystack $32767 needle $20;
  haystack = catx(' ', of D_I10_:);
  needle = 'X45'; link countNeedles; count_X45 = k;
  needle = 'Y15'; link countNeedles; count_Y15 = k;
  needle = 'X65'; link countNeedles; count_X_65 = k;
  return;

countNeedles:
  start = findw(haystack,trim(needle),1);
  do k = 0 by 1 while (start);
    start = findw(haystack,trim(needle),start+1);
  end;
  drop haystack needle start k;
  return;
run;
```

Comment: That is not what the COUNTW() function does.  Count word does not search for strings. It just counts how many words are in the string.  COUNTW(all_D,'X45') says to see how many words there are when any of those three characters are treated as a delimiter between words.

Comment: Eeek, whatta BF I had.  Will have to change to COUNT or looped FINDW